# Am I allowed to use GNU Unifont in a closed source application?

Tags: gpl, commercial, gpl-2, closed-source, gnu

I was looking for a `.ttf` font, where almost all of the unicode characters are created. Then I've found the [GNU Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html)

It is licensed under [GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE Version 2](http://unifoundry.com/LICENSE.txt)

The application I am working on cannot be open sourced (not my choise). It is not just closed-source, but commercial also. Am I allowed to use `GNU Unifont`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the website:

> The precompiled fonts are released under the terms of the GNU GPL
>   version 2, or (at your option) a later version, with the exception
>   that embedding the font in a document does not in itself bind that
>   document to the terms of the GPL.

So, it would be not legal to use GNU Unicode (including the fonts) on any closed-source application, per copyleft licensing terms.

But in your situation, I would strongly recommend that you make use of the open and permissive DejaVu ttf Fonts (http://dejavu-fonts.org) within a font rendering library under a permissive license, on your work.

However there's a GPL exception concerning the use of fonts, made for permitting the non-GPL compatible code to read and write documents and templates that embed the GNU font, as mentioned in [the licensing terms](http://unifoundry.com/LICENSE.txt):

> These font files are licensed under the GNU General Public License,
>   either Version 2 or (at your option) a later version, with the
>   exception that embedding the font in a document does not in itself
>   constitute a violation of the GNU GPL.

Comment: I use SDL_TTF to render text in my game, so if I undestand it correctly, it is legal. Am I allowed to embed it into the executable (`.exe`, `.jar`, etc...) file?

Comment: @IterAtor I'm sorry for being not clear in my answer: It has been corrected now. Please check the update above. If you have any further question please don't hesitate to ask. Best Regards.

Comment: How would including the font in a document template, which is bundled with the application and merely modified by that application, be regarded?

Comment: @rackandboneman Yes, there's already a GPL exception for permitting this. I've made an update to my answer, for further details.